# Remove elements from array based on pattern in bash

Tags: bash

I have an array:

```
list[0]=.abc.com
list[1]=.dd.eu
list[3]=.ww.bb.com
list[4]=.abc.bgs.eu
```

i want to remove all items from array that ends with ".com"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
s='.com'
echo "${list[@]/*$s/}"
 .dd.eu  .abc.bgs.eu
```

Or else to store resulting array in a new array:

```
s='.com'
read -ra arr <<< "${list[@]/*$s/}"
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]=".dd.eu" [1]=".abc.bgs.eu")'
```

Comment: this looks nice and fast : echo "${list[@]/*.com/}" but i need to pass variable to it. The ".com" part must be variable - how to do it ? echo "${list[@]/"$var"/}" does not work

Comment: sure that can be done, see updated answer.

Comment: `declare -p arr` is for printing the array content resulting from `read` call. What I've shown above is output of `declare -p arr`

Comment: Does this approach work when there are spaces in the element strings?

Comment: Would need some tweaking but here OP is dealing with some domain names so space shouldn't be there IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach - make a new array containing the elements you're interested in keeping:

```
new_list=()
for i in "${list[@]}"; do [[ $i != *.com ]] && new_list+=( "$i" ); done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

This stores array results in a different array.

```
declare -a pattern=( ${list[@]/*.com/} )
echo ${pattern[@]}
```

Here list is your array

```
list[0]=.abc.com
list[1]=.dd.eu
list[3]=.ww.bb.com
list[4]=.abc.bgs.eu
```

and pattern is the resulting array with the following output:

```
.dd.eu .abc.bgs.eu
```